# Как правильно правильно прописать пустые активити в manifest?

Tags: android

После того как в студии создается новая активити, в манифесте она прописывается с определенными тегами. Вот как у меня прописана к примеру одна из активити:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondScreenActivity.MainScreen" />
```

эта строка у меня подсвечена желтым цветом и закономерно что студия предлагает свои правки. Вот как студия предлагает исправить эту строку:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondScreenActivity$MainScreen" />
```

но после этих правок слово `SecondScreenActivity` подсвечено красным цветом. Вроде как красный цвет это что-то не очень правильное, потому-что если все правильно то все в зеленом цвете.

Нужно ли принимать правки студии или оставлять все по-старому?

Comment: Прочитал) насколько я понимаю логику ваших комментариев, нужно добавить эту ссылку в комменты и все?)

Comment: Уже другой пользователь опубликовал мою ссылку)

Comment: Тогда пусть тогда вопрос будет лучше удален)

Comment: `SecondScreenActivity` - это класс или пакет? Придерживайтесь правил именования - и проблем меньше будет и код Ваш будет проще читать.

Comment: вероятнее всего это название активити, я если честно не знаю определенных правил наименования, если вам не сложно то уточните что именно вы имели в виду

Comment: [Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html) - прочтите и запомните.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При наведении курсора студия подсказывает

> Use '$' instead of '.' for inner classes (or use only lowercase
>   letters in package names); replace ".SecondScreenActivity.MainScreen"
>   with ".SecondScreenActivity$MainScreen" less... (Ctrl+F1)
>
> When you reference an inner class in a manifest file, you must use '$'
>   instead of '.' as the separator character, i.e. Outer$Inner instead of
>   Outer.Inner.  (If you get this warning for a class which is not
>   actually an inner class, it's because you are using uppercase
>   characters in your package name, which is not conventional.)

Google-перевод

> Используйте '$' вместо '.' для внутренних классов (или используйте
>   только строчные буквы в именах пакетов); замените
>   «.SecondScreenActivity.MainScreen» на «.SecondScreenActivity$MainScreen»
>   меньше ... (Ctrl + F1)
>
> Когда вы ссылаетесь на внутренний класс в файле манифеста, вы должны
>   использовать '$' вместо '.' как символ разделителя, то есть Outer $
>   Inner вместо Outer.Inner. (Если вы получите это предупреждение для
>   класса, который на самом деле не является внутренним классом, это
>   потому, что вы используете заглавные буквы в имени своего пакета, что
>   не является обычным.)

Comment: я задам сейчас возможно тупой вопрос, но что такое внутренний класс? я просто не очень понимаю, я вот попробовал заменить все на $ и у меня полетело приложение при установке на эмулятор. это я так понял что часть классов не является внутренними.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko: Вложенный (внутренний) класс представляет собой любой класс, объявление которого находится в теле другого класса или интерфейса.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, и если этот вложенный класс не имеет модификатора `static`, то он не может быть создан без инстанса класса, в котором он находится. То есть такой класс, прописанный в манифесте система создать не сможет.